# Facing issues attempting to run Selenium tests inside a docker container

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am quite new to Docker and Selenium-related developments and currently, I am working on a Java 17 and Maven 3.9.6-based robotic automation application that automates Chrome through Selenium. to perform report download tasks. This operation works fine when performed in a local development environment and as an executable jar, file.

But when I am attempting to dockerize this application I am facing issues related to selenium and browser dependencies when building and attempting to run the docker image.
Could someone also please suggest if my approach is correct or if it requires any changes or improvements to my Docker file and how the browser dependencies are added?

Could you also suggest some valid resources on how this Java Selenium application can dockerized to be deployed on a new server that does not contain Selenium or Chrome browser functionality currently installed?

After rummaging through a ton of internet resources, forums, and videos to assist with this task my docker files currently look like this.

```
Use the official OpenJDK 17 image as a base image
FROM maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine AS builder

Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod -R 777 /app

Install tools.
RUN apt update -y & apt install -y wget unzip
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get install -y tzdata

Install Chrome.
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

Install ChromeDriver.
RUN wget -N https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/105.0.5195.19/chromedriver_linux64.zip -P ~/
RUN unzip ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d ~/
RUN rm ~/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN mv -f ~/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

Copy the entire project (assuming Dockerfile is in the project root)
COPY . .

Build the application using Maven
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

Use the official OpenJDK 17 image as the final image
FROM eclipse-temurin:17.0.6_10-jdk@sha256:13817c2faa739c0351f97efabed0582a26e9e6745a6fb9c47d17f4365e56327d

Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

Copy the JAR file and other necessary files to the container
COPY report-automation.jar /app/report-automation.jar
COPY src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF /app/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
COPY src /app/src
COPY src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF /app/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
COPY src/main/resources/config.properties /app/config.properties
COPY pom.xml /app/pom.xml
COPY testng.xml /app/testng.xml
COPY application.properties /app/application.properties
COPY Configuration.xlsm /app/Configuration.xlsm
COPY apache-maven-3.9.6/ /app/apache-maven-3.9.6/
COPY Downloads /app/Downloads
COPY Logs /app/Logs
COPY report /app/report
COPY Reports /app/Reports

Expose the port (if your application listens on a specific port)
EXPOSE 8080
Set the entry point for the container (replace with your main class)
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "report-automation.jar"]
```

These are some of the References useful I came across. But I still seem to be missing something.

- [Link 1](https://medium.com/@suni.mothadikala/run-your-selenium-tests-inside-docker-container-part-1-9dfab15d1c86)
- [Link 2](https://dev.to/sunim2022/run-your-selenium-tests-inside-docker-container-part-1-4b02)
- [Link 3](https://medium.com/@amilind29/install-latest-chrome-and-driver-in-linux-docker-image-7120cf6e13d4)
- [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70955307/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: I am getting this error when attempting to run the docker container

sudo docker run selenium_app

[0.003s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "GC Thread#0" - pthread_create failed (EPERM) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 4k, detached.
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /app/hs_err_pid1.log

Comment: Adding --security-opt seccomp=unconfined argument to the docker run command fixed above mentioned  issue. 

docker run --security-opt seccomp=unconfined selenium-app

Refer Links

Resource 1- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443957/insufficient-memory-while-running-eclipse-temurin17-jdk-docker-image
Resource 2 - https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=59421&sid=1726adc6ea305adbd10950335d5a19b4#p59421
Resource 3 - https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/